# pyspark reading csv using pandas, how to keep header

Tags: csv, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading in a csv using pandas chunks functionality. It works, except for I am not able to retain headers. Is there a way/option to do this? here is sample code:

```
import pyspark
import pandas as pd
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="myAppName")
spark_rdd = sc.emptyRDD()

# filename: csv file
chunks = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=10000)
for chunk in chunks:
    spark_rdd +=  sc.parallelize(chunk.values.tolist())

    #print(chunk.head())
    #print(spark_rdd.toDF().show())
    #break

spark_df = spark_rdd.toDF()
spark_df.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import pyspark
import pandas as pd
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="myAppName")
spark_rdd = sc.emptyRDD()

# Read ten rows to get column names
x = pd.read_csv(filename,nrows=10)
mycolumns = list(x)

# filename: csv file
chunks = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=10000)
for chunk in chunks:
    spark_rdd +=  sc.parallelize(chunk.values.tolist())

spark_df = spark_rdd.map(lambda x:tuple(x)).toDF(mycolumns)
spark_df.show()
```

Comment: for reading headers, ``x = pd.read_csv(filename,nrows=1)``  should suffice?

Comment: I agree its arbitrary, won't matter practically if you take 1,5 or 10 rows as long as you take atleast one.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using databricks' spark-csv

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sql = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)

df = sql.read.load(filename, 
                 format='com.databricks.spark.csv', 
                 header='true', 
                 inferSchema='true')
```